# Why is ViewContext.ViewName not available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, viewcontext

I read several examples on the web which use the following code:

```
Private Function SomeFunction(ByVal htmlhelper As HtmlHelper) As String
    Dim controller As Controller = htmlhelper.ViewContext.Controller

    If controller IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim vname as String = htmlhelper.ViewContext.ViewName 'This doesnt work
    End If
End Function
```

**ViewContext does not have a member called ViewName. Am I missing something?**

Refs: 
http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx
[Asp.Net MVC: How to determine if you're currently on a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535/asp-net-mvc-how-to-determine-if-youre-currently-on-a-specific-view)
http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/e5d9e8264c66ba57

Comment: Inside my helpers module... This is a helper function. (but it doesn't even compile...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ViewName` was removed during the betas. Here's two work-arounds:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1334617/2694729.aspx